# Union across databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a large query which I need to adapt so it can query data across several databases (all utilising the same schema). Therefore I am looking to use `UNION` to accomplish the task. However I am not sure how I am supposed to implement database switching. I have already considered switching to three-part-names inside the query, however since the query is quite large and complex, with sub queries, it would be very time consuming. I have also considered using `USE` and copy&pasting the query but I get an error after the second `USE` statement. What would be the best approach to take here? I don't really want to modify the original query too much, since it's working as intended. I am just looking for a way to use the query and get results from multiple databases and then present those in one result set.

Comment: Please post what did you try

Comment: The only way I'm aware of to union across databases is to use three-part names as you've already started doing.

Comment: @Sami: As I wrote I tried using USE and copying the query which resulted in an error after the second attempt "Incorrent syntax near 'USE': Expecting '(' or SELECT. I assume that I can't just stack the code by having USE, SELECTS and UNIONS following each other.

Comment: @Haris Yeah, that what you say, but we need to see it copy it to correct it and give it to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with three part naming.

The beauty of this approach is that you can also do it across linked servers.

e.g.

```
SELECT Thing FROM mydatabase.dbo.Table
UNION
SELECT Thing FROM myotherdatabase.dbo.Table
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I had considered. However since the query is rather complex (i.e. subquerys all written using two or even one part naming) I guess I'll have to touch every single from declaration...

Answer (score 1):

use 3 parts naming convention

```
select  col1, col2, col3 from DB1.dbo.table1
union all
select  col1, col2, col3 from DB2.dbo.table1
```

Comment: OP say `UNION` not `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COLUMNS HERE <Column1, Column2 ...>
FROM TheFirstDataBase.Schema.TableName
UNION
SELECT COLUMNS HERE <Column1, Column2 ...>
FROM TheSecondDataBase.Schema.TableName
```

Note:

It must be the same columns, and the same datatypes.